# How to stream Kodi audio output to a different computer

Tags: kodi

I read topics saying that **Kodi** can stream out its audio to the network and one may listen to it. That is exactly what I want to do, I'd like one **RPi** with Kodi (server) device to play music and stream it out, then another one (client) connects and plays the streaming audio.

I enabled **UPnP/DLNA** on the server (also enabled "**share my libraries**")

Now, on the client side, I can see the server over the network when adding Audio sources.

- If "share my libraries" is enabled, I can select folders to be added (By Artist, Style...), however, they are all empty, anyway, that is not what I want to do, I just want to retrieve what's currently being played by the server...
- If "share my libraries" is disabled, I simply see nothing but empty root folders.

Looks like I'm not configuring the client side correctly. How am I supposed to configure it to retrieve the server's audio stream?